# Проблема с post jquery

Tags: jquery

Когда кликаю по блоку, в блок ничего не записывается.
Когда `$(this).html(data)` заменяю на что-нибудь другое, например, `$('body').html(data)`, ответ сервера пишется в страницу. Что не так?

```
<script src="2.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.div').click(function(){
    $.post('3.php', function(data){
        $(this).html(data);
    });
});
});
</script>
        <div class="div" style="width:100px;height:20px;border:1px solid #ccc"></div>   
    <div class="div" style="width:100px;height:20px;border:1px solid #ccc"></div>   
    <div class="div" style="width:100px;height:20px;border:1px solid #ccc"></div>   
</div>
```

Comment: Помогло!!! Спасибо!!! А почему просто this Не работает?

Comment: Потому что колбэк, который вы передаёте в метод $.post вызывается не в контексте обработчика клика.

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте:

```
var that = this;
$.post('3.php', function(data){
    $(that).html(data);
});
```

> как в таком случае мне записать в div ответ сервера при клике по ссылке?

```
var that = this;
$.post('3.php', function(data){
    $(that).siblings('.div').html(data);
});
```

- [.siblings()](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/)

Comment: Как в таком случае мне записать в div ответ сервера при клике по ссылке?

Блок и ссылка выводятся в цикле, например, и их несколько

`<div class="div"></div>
<a href="#">Ссыль</a>`